# Using spherical coordinates, show that $\nabla \wedge( \cos(\theta)\nabla\phi)=\nabla(1/r)$ 

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Having problems with how to obtain the following, I have written in my notes but can't see how the end result is formed.

> Using spherical co-ordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ evaluate $\nabla \phi$ and show that $\nabla \wedge( \cos(\theta)\nabla\phi)=\nabla(1/r)$

Now ${\mathbf r} = x \mathbf{i}+y \mathbf{j}+z \mathbf{k}= r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) \mathbf{i} + r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \mathbf{j} + r \cos(\theta) \mathbf{k}$

It says that $\nabla \phi$ = $\frac {1}{r\sin(\theta)} {\bf e_{\phi}}$

I'm just confused to how you get to this?

As for the $\nabla \wedge( \cos(\theta)\nabla\phi)=\nabla(1/r)$ this makes more sense to me, once the first part is obtained.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, establish what $\mathbf{e}_r$, $\mathbf{e}_\phi$ and $\mathbf{e}_\theta$ are.
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \mathbf{e}_r &=& \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) \mathbf{i} + \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \mathbf{j} + \cos(\theta) \mathbf{k} \\
   \mathbf{e}_\theta &=& \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) \mathbf{i} + \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) \mathbf{j} - \sin(\theta) \mathbf{k} \\
   \mathbf{e}_\phi &=& - \sin(\phi) \mathbf{i} + \cos(\phi) \mathbf{j}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
They form orthonormal system $\langle \mathbf{e}_r, \mathbf{e}_r \rangle = \langle \mathbf{e}_\phi, \mathbf{e}_\phi \rangle = \langle \mathbf{e}_\theta, \mathbf{e}_\theta \rangle = 1$, $\langle \mathbf{e}_r, \mathbf{e}_\phi \rangle = \langle \mathbf{e}_r, \mathbf{e}_\theta \rangle = \langle \mathbf{e}_\phi, \mathbf{e}_\theta \rangle = 0$.
Now
$$
  \nabla \phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \mathbf{i} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \mathbf{j} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} \mathbf{k}
$$
To compute partial derivatives, use
$$
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial r}{\partial z} \\
  \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} \\
 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
   \begin{pmatrix} 
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) & r \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) & -r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \\
  \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) & r \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi)& r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) \\
\cos(\theta) & -r \sin(\theta) & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
  \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) & \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) & \cos(theta) \\
  \frac{\cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) }{r} & \frac{\cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) }{r} & -\frac{\sin(\theta) }{r} \\
   -\frac{\sin(\phi)}{r \cos(\theta)} & \frac{\cos(\phi)}{r \cos(\theta)} & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus
$$
   \nabla \phi = -\frac{\sin(\phi)}{r \cos(\theta)}  \mathbf{i} + \frac{\cos(\phi)}{r \cos(\theta)} \mathbf{j} = \frac{1}{r \cos(\theta)} \mathbf{e}_\phi 
$$

Comment: Perfect thank you very much